# Would I use core data?

Tags: ios, swift

So I have a process for a user to take a photo add info and upload to my database. My question is how should I store that data so it is accessible through all my controllers and when they click the upload button it sends the final object to the server to be added to the database. Would I use core data? Or like a struct? I just want to make sure I am doing this correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an opinion oriented answer and it is influenced by developer's familiarity/comfort with the various underlying concepts as well. Hence though I dont consider it as an answer here is my opinion.

> Should I use core data,  so it is accessible through all my controllers?

Absolutely no! U don't need core data, just to create a shared data source which is being used by multiple ViewController's simultaneously. You can obviously create a Singleton data source object and can be accessed by all the VC's.

But then, core data is not just a shared data source isn't it ?

**Core data is a Persistent Data Store where as your structs are not.**

Assume user takes a pic, and before it gets uploaded quits the app, or you want to provide offline capability to user, where user can take a pic without internet and queue it for upload and whenever internet comes back your app loads it to server, if u use structs and keep data source in memory, if user quits the app all the efforts done by user to will go waste and obviously user will not appreciate it. On the other hand if u use core data you can obviously have it in sqlite file, and then access it whenever u need it even if user quits the app in between :)

**Managed Object Context provides performBlock and performBlockAndWait to synchronize the access to core data in multi threaded environment but with a plain array of struct u have to write it on ur own.**

Now there is no point in reinventing the wheel isn't it? We all know data types like array are not thread safe :) So is managedObject Context but managedObject context on iOS 5 onwards provides the amazing handy methods like  performBlock and performBlockAndWait which eases the life of developer when dealing with shared data source (managedObject) in multi threaded environment.

**Managed Object Context provides notifications about the changes happening in real time and works like a charm with NSFetchedResultsController providing a mechanism to constatly monitor and update the data source**

I dont think its a big thing, but in order to achieve the same thing with array u'll have to use KVO. But because KVO wont work with swift objects u'll have to override `didSet` method and manually throw notification to all VC's when data source changes. Not so elegant solution isn't it :)

**Scalability and robustness :**

Finally, how many records are u dealing with also matters. I have been a part of a company which uploads and restores thousands of images on/from users device. In a scenario where you are dealing with 1000s of images maintaining a array is always a pain and memory print costly as well because the entire array will be loaded all the time. On the other hand `NSFetchedResultsController` works on page fault mechanism. It loads data efficiently only when needed.

Scalability is just a matter of adding new fields to managed object entity and robustness is directly proportional to you skill set dealing with core data I believe.

**Pinch of Advice :**

No matter whether u use array of structs or Core Data, always store images in local file system and keep the local path relative reference in your data source. Holding an entire an image in memory is a real bad idea :D

Hope it helps.